# Redis docker container not coming up with custom config file

Tags: docker, redis

I'm using the below command to run the Redis docker container

```
docker run -tid -v /data1/REDIS_DOCKER_IMAGE/6379/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/6379/redis.conf
-p 6379:6379 --name node_6379  redis:5.0.8 redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

After I run this command, I check `"docker ps"` but it comes up empty. There are no logs shown by `docker logs` so I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in my custom config file I had the `daemonize` option enabled and after disabling that my container is working fine.